# Does firestore support the BETWEEN condition in where clause

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Using firestore, I have a collection of PRODUCTS that will available for booking for exactly 3 days. So I am keeping the bookingStartsOn and bookingEndsOn as an attribute within products collection(Unix format).

Now, I want to filter the products that are available for specific date range like (21-09-2019 to 23-09-2019).

Could you please help me in this regard because I am unable to find the BETWEEN condition in WHERE clause.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a where clause you'll reach the limitation of only being able to use one comparison operator (`>=`, `>`, `<`, `<=`) per query, so you would essentially only be able to find all values greater than a date (fine if you're just looking for dates from the last 7 days and have nothing stored in the future), but won't let you do the operation like you've shown as an example `21-09-2019 to 23-09-2019`.

For that, there are other parameters that will work better than a where clause here. In Firestore you can use `startAt(), endAt(),` to be inclusive of what you provide, or `startAfter(), endBefore()`.

In order for the startAt type operators to be effective here, you will want to use them in conjunction with `orderBy`. Essentially what you will be instructing Firestore to do is to first consider all of the items in order of time, and then only return dates in a long sequential list that meet your start and end times.

These should do the trick, and you can read about them and their requirements here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html